# Wrong CIFAR-10 data format in convolution neural network

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

i have imported   data as following

```
from keras.datasets import cifar10
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
(X_train,y_train),(X_test,y_test) =cifar10.load_data()
for i in range(9):
  plt.subplot(330+1+i)
  plt.imshow(X_train[i])
plt.show()
```

it works fine as it is given in result :

[image]

next i have defined  following convolution neural network structure

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.constraints import max_norm
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Convolution2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.utils import np_utils
model =Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(filters=32,kernel_size=3,input_shape=(3,32,32),padding='same',activation='relu',data_format='channels_first',kernel_constraint=max_norm(3)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Convolution2D(filters=32,kernel_size=3,activation='relu',padding='same',kernel_constraint=max_norm(3)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(units=512,activation='relu',kernel_constraint=max_norm(3)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes,activation='softmax'))
```

i have done all necessary compile  procedures

```
Epochs=25
lrate =0.01
decay =lrate /epochs
sgd =SGD(learning_rate=decay,momentum=0.9,nesterov=False)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy' , optimizer='sgd', metrics=['accuracy' ])
print(model.summary())
```

and result is here:

[image]

after runing following code

```
model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test),epochs=Epochs,batch_size=32, verbose=2)
# Final evaluation of the model
scores = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print("Accuracy: %.2f%%" % (scores[1]*100))
```

it gives me error :

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_7 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis 1 of input shape to have value 3 but received input with shape [None, 32, 32, 3]
```

please help me to fix this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input shape in your first convolutional layer should be input_shape=(32,32,3) instead of input_shape=(3,32,32). You should also set the data_format to the default "channels_last". The reason for setting it up like this is that the shape of cifar10 images is (32,32,3) and not (3,32,32)

Answer (score 1):

you should always be careful about the input shape of the first layer of CNN using Conv2D. In tensorflow the input shape parameters are given as (batch_size, img_h, img_w, channels).

In contrary to pytorch it is (batch_size, channels, img_h, img_w). So, it should be (32,32,3) not (3, 32, 32).